# Buying a New home for my Family

Tags: united-states, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer, home-loan

Recently we had a baby and planning to buy a home. Is now a good time to buy a home? In my area houses are around 650K. I have the following questions.

1. Is it good time to buy a home?
2. Interest rate mortgage companies are charging @ 5-5.25%. Is it high?
3. Is it really worth it or stay in a rented home?
4. Mortgage company asking us to put 72K down payment but we have only
   20K. What should I do now?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: SanFrancisco, California

Comment: Or this? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/in-general-is-it-financially-better-to-buy-or-to-rent-a-house

Comment: Whoops, just meant to post that as another potential duplicate forgot that it would close automatically.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing your income. Can you afford buying a house ? 20k isn't a lot and you definitely shouldn't buy a house until you have a bit more than that

Comment: We're in a recession.  Home prices decline during a recession, sometimes moderately, sometimes severely (see 2008). Coincidentally, my nephew called me a week ago and he and his wife are on the verge of buying a $500k home.  I suggested that he wait.  Home prices are not going to melt up.  At worst, they'll stagnate.  It's not like it's a one of a kind rare painting.  There are always going to be homes available.  AFAIC, the one exception to this might be  if you have found a distressed property selling for well below the market.

Comment: Thanks @BobBaerker I am planning to wait. I am confused here, if we are in recession how come the stocks and real estate market is going up and up? How buyers are buying for this huge price?

Comment: @Test - In 2008-09 when the DJIA dropped from 14,000+ to 6,500+, there were two days in October '08  when the DJIA rose over 1,000 points.  That's over a 13% gain on two different days in the same month.  The market can rise during a bear market.  If it's a short term rally after a hard selloff, it's called a Dead Cat Bounce.  My guess is that the $2 trillion in stimulus and $4 trillion of Fed liquidity is buoying the market with the expectation that such unprecedented largesse solves a shuttered economy.  I don't see it.  Either way, home prices take time to react.

Comment: 16 million people just lost their jobs and likely, more job losses to come.  A $1,200 stimulus check and maybe $600 a week in unemployment isn't going to pay the rent and that's assuming that it begins arriving in a timely fashion.  It won't because the government is inefficient. Some will slip through the cracks.  Some states have barred eviction for a period of time if rent not paid.  How will landlords not receiving rent be able to pay their mortgages? In such a scenario, do you see home prices rising?  If anything, likely to go down.